# Squeeze theorem for riemann integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, logic, quantifiers, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

> $\text{Squeeze theorem :}$ Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists functions $\alpha_\epsilon$ and $\omega_\epsilon$ in $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $$\alpha_\epsilon\le f(x)\le\omega_\epsilon\space \text{for all}\space x\in[a,b]$$ and such that $$\int\limits_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)<\epsilon$$

**Question :** What is the negation of the squeeze theorem? Would the following work?
$f\notin \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ if and only if there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all functions $\alpha_\epsilon$ and $\omega_\epsilon$ in $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $\alpha_\epsilon\le f(x)\le\omega_\epsilon\space \text{for all}\space x\in[a,b]$ we have $\int\limits_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)\ge\epsilon$

Comment: formalize the theorem in the language of first order logic and carry out the negation. hint: the negation establishes the existence of a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $P$ the proposition "$f\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$", and by $Q$ the proposition "*for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists... such that...*"
The squeeze theorem states that $(P\Rightarrow Q)\land(Q\Rightarrow P)$. Hence the nagation of it is $(\lnot(P\Rightarrow Q))\lor(\lnot(Q\Rightarrow P))$.
We see $\lnot(P\Rightarrow Q)$ may be stated as:

> There exists a function $f\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ such that $\lnot Q$ is true, i.e., such that the following holds:
>
> > There exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any function $\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ satisfying $\alpha_\epsilon\leq f\leq\omega_\epsilon$, we have
> >     $$\int_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)dx\geq\epsilon$$

On the other hand, $\lnot(Q\Rightarrow P)$ is

> There exists a function $f\not\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ such that $Q$ is true, i.e., such that the following holds:
>
> > For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a pair of functions $\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ satisfying $\alpha_\epsilon\leq f\leq\omega_\epsilon$ such that
> >     $$\int_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)dx<\epsilon$$

The negation of the squeeze theorem is of the form "$A$ or $B$", where $A,B$ is the two propositions stated above.

Comment: How did you arrive at $\lnot Q$? I don't know logic, the symbols in your answer looked new to me and I had to google. But I figured it out, for me the problem remains to find '$\lnot Q$'.It seems to me that $Q$ means $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\forall x\in[a,b])$  $(\exists\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $\alpha_\epsilon\le f(x)\le\omega_\epsilon\space)$ $\big(\int\limits_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)<\epsilon\big)$.

Comment: But then $\lnot Q$ means $(\exists\epsilon>0)(\exists x\in[a,b])$  $(\forall\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $\alpha_\epsilon\le f(x)\le\omega_\epsilon\space)$ $\big(\int\limits_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)\ge\epsilon\big)$

Comment: @BijeshK.S You're almost right, but $\lnot Q$ means $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon \in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $(\forall x\in[a,b])(\alpha_\epsilon\le f(x)\le\omega_\epsilon\space))\big(\int\limits_a^b(\omega_\epsilon-\alpha_\epsilon)<\epsilon\big)$. To see why this holds, note that $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha_\epsilon\leq f\leq \omega_\epsilon$ is a property $X$ of the function pair $\alpha_\epsilon,\omega_\epsilon$. $Q$ states "for any $\epsilon$ there exists some function pair with property $X$ satisfying..."

Comment: So the negation of $Q$ should be "there exists some $\epsilon$ such that any function pair with property $X$ won't satisfy..."  You may wonder that this is not a exact negation. The exact one should be "for any $\epsilon$, any function pair at least does not satisfy one of $X$ and the integral being small than $\epsilon$". That's true, but in practice(instead of in formal logic) we often take the non-exact statement, since there obviously exists a function pair satisfying $X$.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, you couldn't say any better. The above two comments were exactly what I needed!! Thank you

Comment: Let me clarify this once again.... What is that obvious function pair satisfying $X$?

Comment: For example, $\alpha_\epsilon(x)$ is a constant function equal to $\inf f(x)$ and $\omega_\epsilon$ being $\sup f$.

Comment: What if $f$ is unbounded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46854/discussion-between-cave-johnson-and-bijesh-k-s).